# Create a model instance with InlinePanel in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail

do you have any idea how can I create an instance of the model by using InlinePanel
I do not want to add an existing already one instance but I want to create a new one along with the `ParentalKey`

in my case, the `ParentalKey` is the family and the person is the `ForeignKey`
[here the documentation about wagtail InlinePanel](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.3/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels-and-model-clusters)

```py
@register_snippet
class Family(ClusterableModel):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("family title"), max_length=100)
    panels = Page.content_panels + [        
        InlinePanel("persons", label=_("Persons")),
    ]

class FamilyPerson(Orderable):
    person = models.ForeignKey("crm.Person", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    family = ParentalKey(
        "crm.Family", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="persons"
    )


@register_snippet
class Person(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = [("M", _("Male")), ("F", _("Female"))]
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("person title"), max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_("age")
    )
    sex = models.CharField(
        max_length=12, choices=SEX_CHOICES
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```py
@register_snippet
class Family(ClusterableModel):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("family title"), max_length=100)
    panels = Page.content_panels + [        
        InlinePanel("persons", label=_("Persons")),
    ]

class Person(Orderable):
    family = ParentalKey(
        "crm.Family", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="persons"
    )
    SEX_CHOICES = [("M", _("Male")), ("F", _("Female"))]
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("person title"), max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_("age")
    )
    sex = models.CharField(
        max_length=12, choices=SEX_CHOICES
```

that is it! I just complicated it, it was so simple